# How can I get the href value of clicked element?

Tags: javascript, html, confirm

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/master/bootbox.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a onclick="return bootbox.confirm('are you sure?', function(e){ if (e) {window.location = this.href;} });" href="/Remove-Post/{{ $tb }}/{{$post->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">Link</a>
```

Noted that I use [this library](http://bootboxjs.com/) for `confirm`.

But this line doesn't work in my code:

```
window.location = this.href;
```

And it always *(when I click <kbd>OK</kbd>)* redirects me here:

```
http://localhost:8000/undefined
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: $tb is undefined. Are you using any template engine or framework?

Comment: Wouldn't you use e.target instead of this?

Comment: can you make a js fiddle? @stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a onclick="return bootbox.confirm('are you sure?', function(e){ if (e) {window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');} });" href="/Remove-Post/{{ $tb }}/{{$post->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
```

Instead of `onClick` you can do something like this.

```
<a id="some-id" href="/Remove-Post/{{ $tb }}/{{$post->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
$('#some-id').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    bootbox.confirm('are you sure ?', function(e){
      if(e){
         window.location.href = link;
       }
    })
})
```

Comment: still it redirects me to `undefined` page

Comment: can you create a simple fiddle ? or give me moment I'll create it for you.

Comment: ok, I removed `link` from function(e, link){, and now it works as well, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your code the  `this.href` doesn't work because of `this` is refering to the `bootbox` object and this last doesn't have an href property :

What I suggest to you is just using a common function that is used to show the dialog and in the same way you can use several  each one redirect to a url. and also and set dynamicly the dialog title by passing it as a parameter,

Here is a snippet :
 ( I have replaced location.href by conosle.log to prevent redirecting ...)

```js
function redirect(node,message) {
  if(!message) message ="";
  return bootbox.confirm(message, function(e){ if (e) {
    // we use console instead of redirecting directly 
    console.log(node.href);
    // location.href = node.href; 
  } });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>



<a onclick="redirect(this,'are you sure ?');" href="http://www.google.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">link 1</a>
<br>
<a onclick="redirect(this,'leave the page  ?');" href="http://www.bing.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">link 2</a>
<br>
<a onclick="redirect(this,'are you sure to leave !! ?');" href="http://www.yahoo.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">link 1</a>
```

Comment: @stack you can use a function for and optimised solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will give you a pop up if you click on yes then it will processed further otherwise stay on same page.
Try this.

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');" href="/Remove-Post/{{ $tb }}/{{$post->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootbox is a third party plugin. You cannot access this pointer inside the bootbox confirm callback function. You have to save this.href in a local variable first before calling bootbox there after use the local variable inside the bootbox confirm callback.

```
<a onclick="NavigatePage()" href="/Remove-Post/{{ $tb }}/{{$post->id}}"/>

function NavigatePage(){
   var URL = this.href;  
   bootbox.confirm('are you sure?', function(UserResponse){
    if (UserResponse) {
      window.location = URL
    } 
   });
 }
```

In your case you will get undefined because you are accessing `this` object inside the bootbox callback function. Inside the call back `this` object is not accessible.

Answer (score -3):

Is `this.ref` in scope of the function?
*Wrote my last lines of JS two years ago...*

Edit:
I remember, problem is the return value. If it is not flase. It will move to the href location.

Do not have your libary, but you can adapt it:

```html
<a onclick="if(confirm('are you sure?')) { alert(this.href);};return false;" href="/Remove-Post/{{ $tb }}/{{$post->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">Click me</a>
```

Edit 2:
Before stupidly down voting, you should try the code. It works.